# laravel/lumen-framework 5.8.x-dev requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I'm trying to run...

```
composer require diglactic/laravel-breadcrumbs
```

And I'm getting this error because of my PHP version. Can someone help?

> laravel/lumen-framework 5.8.x-dev requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP
> version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement

My composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/lumen",
    "description": "The Laravel Lumen Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel", "lumen"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "laravel/legacy-factories": "^1.1",
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "^8.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.6",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^6.1",
        "vluzrmos/tinker": "^1.4",
        "wn/lumen-generators": "^1.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ]
    }
}
```

Full Error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/lumen-framework 5.8.x-dev requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/lumen-framework 5.7.x-dev requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/lumen-framework 5.6.x-dev requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for vluzrmos/tinker ^1.4 -> satisfiable by vluzrmos/tinker[v1.4.0].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/lumen-framework v8.2.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/lumen-framework v8.2.3
    - vluzrmos/tinker v1.4.0 requires laravel/lumen-framework ^5.3 -> satisfiable by laravel/lumen-framework[5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/lumen-framework[5.3.x-dev, v8.2.3].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/lumen-framework[5.4.x-dev, v8.2.3].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/lumen-framework[5.5.x-dev, v8.2.3].
    - Installation request for laravel/lumen-framework (locked at v8.2.3, required as ^8.0) -> satisfiable by laravel/lumen-framework[v8.2.3].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: What version of Laravel do you have installed?

Comment: My Laravel version is 8.0

Comment: Can you provide the full error dump?

Comment: Actually, it might be `wn/lumen-generators` throwing the error, because it's meant for Laravel 5, not 8. **Edit** The full dump says it's `vluzrmos/tinker` requiring Laravel 5. The [github page](https://github.com/vluzrmos/lumen-tinker) says it's abandoned and to use the official Laravel tinker instead

Comment: Why are you using other tinker than laravel ?

Comment: Maintainer of `diglactic/laravel-breadcrumbs` here. Like others have mentioned, doesn't seem to be an issue with that package. Feel free to open an issue (https://github.com/diglactic/laravel-breadcrumbs/issues) if that changes.

Answer (score 1):

have you try this code?

```
composer require davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs:5.2.1
```

if still does'nt work you can try

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```